# Regex pattern not working in AEM Templates-allowedPaths property

Tags: regex, aem, regex-negation

```
(?=(/content/xxx/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/*))(?=(^(?:(?!sample1|sample2).)*).*)
```

This is my regex pattern to limit my visibility of templates under some path and avoid being created under specific folders.
Could anyone figure out any issue or suggest some other ways?

Comment: I guess i can not help you until you send me everything thats in `content/xxx/` (not just the samples pls) ;)

Comment: /content/atm/en/marketing/royalty/                                                                    Under royalty, there are many folders like sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4. My requirement is to block the template under sample1,sample2, but that templates should be available in other sub folders(eg sample3,sample4)

Comment: Hm, thats dissapointing. However, I think I don't get the question. With regex-questions, its always helpful to provide a list of stings and desired matches and strings where things shouldn't be matched. Thats the easiest way to point out the expected behaviour with regex. Also, based on the expression you provided, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Likewise, the template should be available under fourth level of tree in content/xxx/

Comment: When I try in online regex/ it works fine. The folders-sample1,sample2 represents content-promotion,desire-activation-image.                                                   Whenever I enter the second regex condition,the templates getting hidden.If I enter first part of regex alone, it works fine. The problem is with the second part of regex expression where I am checking for the folder name.

Comment: Try [`^/content/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(?![^/]*/(?:sample1|sample2))([^/]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/rVeSdS/2).

Comment: It works fine now. Thank you Wiktor Stribizew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^/content/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(?![^/]*/(?:sample1|sample2))([^/]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rVeSdS/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `/content/` - a literal substring
- `([^/]*)/` - 0+ chars other than `/` and a `/`
- `([^/]*)/([^/]*)/` - 2 previous subpatterns on end
- `(?![^/]*/(?:sample1|sample2))` - a *negative lookahead* that fails the match if there are any 0+ chars other than `/`, then `/` and either `sample1` or `sample2` immediately to the right of the current location
- `([^/]*)` - 0+ chars other than `/`

Note that if you are not using submatches, the pattern can be shortened to

```
^/content/(?:[^/]*/){3}(?![^/]*/(?:sample1|sample2))[^/]*
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/FDoo2c/1)